# SQL Count multiple fields in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, union

I would like to count how many `idA` from table `A` exists in fields `idA_1-3` in table `B` and replace 0 with null in output.

```
A       B
idA     idB   idA_1 idA_2 idA_3
1       1     2     3     3
2       2     2     3     3
3       3     1     3     2
        4     3     1     2
        5     1     1     2
```

Desired output:

```
idA     cA_1  cA_2  cA_3
1       2     2    
2       2           3
3       1     3     2
```

The query that counts only cA_1 looks like following, but I failed to modify it to include more columns:

```
SELECT IdA, COUNT(*) AS cA_1 FROM
(SELECT A.IdA, B.IdB
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.IdA = B.IdA_1)
WHERE IdB IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY IdA
UNION ALL SELECT IdA, NULL AS cA_1 FROM
(SELECT A.IdA, B.IdB
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.IdA = B.IdA_1)
WHERE IdB IS NULL
GROUP BY IdA;
```

There is also an option with `IIF` but it works too slow:

```
SELECT A.IdA, IIf((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE IdA_1 = A.IdA)=0, NULL, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE IdA_1 = A.IdA)) AS cA_1
FROM A;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest correlated subqueries:

```
select a.id,
       (select count(*) from b where b.idA_1 = a.id) as a_1,
       (select count(*) from b where b.idA_2 = a.id) as a_2,
       (select count(*) from b where b.idA_3 = a.id) as a_3
from a;
```

You can use the use `iif()` to convert the `NULL`s to 0:

```
select id, iif(a_1 > 0, a_1, NULL) as a_1,
       iif(a_2 > 0, a_2, NULL) as a_2,
       iif(a_3 > 0, a_3, NULL) as a_3
from (select a.id,
             (select count(*) from b where b.idA_1 = a.id) as a_1,
             (select count(*) from b where b.idA_2 = a.id) as a_2,
             (select count(*) from b where b.idA_3 = a.id) as a_3
      from a
     ) as a;
```

Most databases have a function called `nullif()`, but I don't think there is a corresponding function in MS Access.

Comment: Works like a charm with minor fixes (id -> idA and change a_1-3 -> cA_1-3 to avoid circular ref in the first select of the second example. Thanks a lot!